# C# Getting the rows of Matrices

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

For one of my university projects, we are required to code our own mathematical functions in Unity. Some of the preset mathematical functions we can use, but we have to create some of them ourselves too as part of the coursework.

At the moment, I'm currently stuck on transposing my rotation matrix (pitch, yaw, and roll), and also getting the row's of my matrix.
We've been given a basic information, which we need to create a method that gets the row of my Matrix4by4.

We have been given this as a start;

```
public Matrix4by4 RotationInverse()
{
     //GetRow is a method you'll need to create yourself
     return new Matrix4by4(GetRow(0), GetRow(1), GetRow(2), GetRow(3));
}
```

where we have to create the GetRow Method our self.

Here's the code for my Matrix4by4 method

```
        public static Matrix4by4 operator *(Matrix4by4 lhs, Matrix4by4 rhs)
        {
            Matrix4by4 rv = Identity;

            //vector.w = 1.0f; //Forcing the W component to 1 for translation Matrix. As Unity is converting a Vector4 to a Vector3 implicitly, the W component is set to 0 by default.
                             //With a translation component, the W component must be 1.

            rv.values[0, 0] = lhs.values[0, 0] * rhs.values[0, 0] + lhs.values[0, 1] * rhs.values[1 ,0] + lhs.values[0, 2] * rhs.values[2, 0] + lhs.values[0, 3] * rhs.values[3, 0];
            rv.values[1, 0] = lhs.values[1, 0] * rhs.values[0, 0] + lhs.values[1, 1] * rhs.values[1, 0] + lhs.values[1, 2] * rhs.values[2, 0] + lhs.values[1, 3] * rhs.values[3, 0];
            rv.values[2, 0] = lhs.values[2, 0] * rhs.values[0, 0] + lhs.values[2, 1] * rhs.values[1, 0] + lhs.values[2, 2] * rhs.values[2, 0] + lhs.values[2, 3] * rhs.values[3, 0];
            rv.values[3, 0] = lhs.values[3, 0] * rhs.values[0, 0] + lhs.values[3, 1] * rhs.values[1, 0] + lhs.values[3, 2] * rhs.values[2, 0] + lhs.values[3, 3] * rhs.values[3, 0];

            rv.values[0, 1] = lhs.values[0, 0] * rhs.values[0, 1] + lhs.values[0, 1] * rhs.values[1, 1] + lhs.values[0, 2] * rhs.values[2, 1] + lhs.values[0, 3] * rhs.values[3, 1];
            rv.values[1, 1] = lhs.values[1, 0] * rhs.values[0, 1] + lhs.values[1, 1] * rhs.values[1, 1] + lhs.values[1, 2] * rhs.values[2, 1] + lhs.values[1, 3] * rhs.values[3, 1];
            rv.values[2, 1] = lhs.values[2, 0] * rhs.values[0, 1] + lhs.values[2, 1] * rhs.values[1, 1] + lhs.values[2, 2] * rhs.values[2, 1] + lhs.values[2, 3] * rhs.values[3, 1];
            rv.values[3, 1] = lhs.values[3, 0] * rhs.values[0, 1] + lhs.values[3, 1] * rhs.values[1, 1] + lhs.values[3, 2] * rhs.values[2, 1] + lhs.values[3, 3] * rhs.values[3, 1];

            rv.values[0, 2] = lhs.values[0, 0] * rhs.values[0, 2] + lhs.values[0, 1] * rhs.values[1, 2] + lhs.values[0, 2] * rhs.values[2, 2] + lhs.values[0, 3] * rhs.values[3, 2];
            rv.values[1, 2] = lhs.values[1, 0] * rhs.values[0, 2] + lhs.values[1, 1] * rhs.values[1, 2] + lhs.values[1, 2] * rhs.values[2, 2] + lhs.values[1, 3] * rhs.values[3, 2];
            rv.values[2, 2] = lhs.values[2, 0] * rhs.values[0, 2] + lhs.values[2, 1] * rhs.values[1, 2] + lhs.values[2, 2] * rhs.values[2, 2] + lhs.values[2, 3] * rhs.values[3, 2];
            rv.values[3, 2] = lhs.values[3, 0] * rhs.values[0, 2] + lhs.values[3, 1] * rhs.values[1, 2] + lhs.values[3, 2] * rhs.values[2, 2] + lhs.values[3, 3] * rhs.values[3, 2];

            rv.values[0, 3] = lhs.values[0, 0] * rhs.values[0, 3] + lhs.values[0, 1] * rhs.values[1, 3] + lhs.values[0, 2] * rhs.values[2, 3] + lhs.values[0, 3] * rhs.values[3, 3];
            rv.values[1, 3] = lhs.values[1, 0] * rhs.values[0, 3] + lhs.values[1, 1] * rhs.values[1, 3] + lhs.values[1, 2] * rhs.values[2, 3] + lhs.values[1, 3] * rhs.values[3, 3];
            rv.values[2, 3] = lhs.values[2, 0] * rhs.values[0, 3] + lhs.values[2, 1] * rhs.values[1, 3] + lhs.values[2, 2] * rhs.values[2, 3] + lhs.values[2, 3] * rhs.values[3, 3];
            rv.values[3, 3] = lhs.values[3, 0] * rhs.values[0, 3] + lhs.values[3, 1] * rhs.values[1, 3] + lhs.values[3, 2] * rhs.values[2, 3] + lhs.values[3, 3] * rhs.values[3, 3];

            return rv;
        }
```

I have an Identity Matrix where I pass a new matrix into each time

```
        public static Matrix4by4 Identity
        {
            get
            {
                return new Matrix4by4(
                    new Vector4(1, 0, 0, 0),
                    new Vector4(0, 1, 0, 0),
                    new Vector4(0, 0, 1, 0),
                    new Vector4(0, 0, 0, 1));
            }
        }
```

And I've got a method that Inverses the translation

```
public Matrix4by4 TranslationInverse()
{
   Matrix4by4 rv = Identity;

   rv.values[0,3] = -values[0,3];
   rv.values[1,3] = -values[1,3];
   rv.values[2,3] = -values[2,3];

   return rv;
}
```

Been trying for a few hours to try and figure it out, but I'm having no luck.

Comment: What is GetRow() acting on? Is it a static method? If so, you'd need to pass in a matrix, along with the row to pull out of that matrix (say: GetRow(myMatrix, 0)). If it's a method which acts on a matrix (say: myMatrix.GetRow(0)) then it would act on myMatrix. Once you're in a matrix it's pretty straightforward. Just loop over all columns in a row and add them to a Row collection (say List<node> Row; Row.Add(somevalue)).

Comment: I've just spoken to my lecturer, and he's give me this bit of advice. ``` Your constructor will take in 4x Vector4 arguments and insert the values (x, y, z, w) into the matrix values as columns 0, 1, 2 and 3.

This function works with those concepts in mind and needs to return a Vector4 that hold a row (acquired from the matrix values). The number passed in corresponds to the row number. ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix class is called Matrix4x4 in Unity3D, heres the reference http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Matrix4x4.html

You can extract vector4's using GetRow and set them back using SetRow for example, a complete roundtrip can be achieved like this:

```
    Vector4 row0=matrix.GetRow(0);
    Vector4 row1=matrix.GetRow(1);
    Vector4 row2=matrix.GetRow(2);
    Vector4 row3=matrix.GetRow(3);
    matrix.SetRow(0,row0);
    matrix.SetRow(1,row1);
    matrix.SetRow(2,row2);
    matrix.SetRow(3,row3);
```

from where implementing your task should be fairly trivial. You could rewrap it into a float[x,y] or, even better float [x][y] to keep your syntax similar but will be effectively the same - I belive four structs are faster than four arrays

edit: since you mentioned your Matrix4by4 class is indeed custom, but you didn't post its code, we can guess that it has a 2d matrix internal backing field called values. In that case your getRow method would look something like

```
public Vector4 GetRow(int rowIndex)
{
return new Vector4(values[0,rowIndex],
values[1,rowIndex]
values[2,rowIndex]
values[3,rowIndex]);
}
```

Comment: Yeah Matrix4by4 is custom. We have to implement some of the math functions ourselves as part of the course work. So we're not allowed to use Matrix4x4.

Comment: Thank you for that! Yeah, the matrix is pretty much set up like this `values[0,0] = column1.x; values[1,0] = column.y; values[2,0] = column.z; values[3,0] = column.w;` etc